Reducing load of calculating the length of network in PyQGIS
I am trying to calculate the length of a network by creating a length field and giving it an expression of $length. I have approximately 3000 features in the layer.
I tried two ways:

By giving default expression and iterating through features with giving each feature value of 1
The normal way to by using QgsExpressionContext and giving each feature an expression

Although the second method takes comparatively less time than the first method, it still takes 30 seconds. I am storing data locally on my computer. The number of vertices is 6636 also, if I delete that field and rerun the code, QGIS crashes.
How can I reduce the time required to calculate in these operations?
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

def pipe_f():
    Pipe_name = "PIPE"
    Pipe = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(Pipe_name)[0]
    Pipe.startEditing()
    
    #For Length
    
    Length = QgsField('LENGTH', QVariant.Double, len=10, prec=2)  
    Pipe.dataProvider().addAttributes([Length])
    Pipe.updateFields()
    
    # Loop through features and update the field
    for feature in Pipe.getFeatures():
        # Create an expression context for evaluating the expression
        context = QgsExpressionContext()
        context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(Pipe))

        # Define the expression
        expression_str = "$length"
        
        # Evaluate the expression for each feature
        expression = QgsExpression(expression_str)
        context.setFeature(feature)
        value = expression.evaluate(context)

        # Update the new field with the calculated value
        Pipe.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), Pipe.fields().indexOf('LENGTH'), value)
    length_field = "LENGTH"
    length_expression = "$length"
    def attLength(Pipe, length_field):
        config =  {'IsMultiline': False, 'UseHtml': False }
        
        Pipe.editFormConfig().setWidgetConfig("TextEdit", config)
        default_Length = QgsDefaultValue()   
        default_Length.setApplyOnUpdate(True)
        default_Length.setExpression(length_expression) 
        
        Length_index = Pipe.fields().indexFromName(length_field)
        
        # Set the default value for the specific field
        Pipe.setDefaultValueDefinition(Length_index, default_Length)
    attLength(Pipe, length_field)
pipe_f()


You don't mention the data storage format or location, or the number of vertices involved, which probably has a lot more to do with duration of length calculation than anything else you've provided. Please [Edit] the Question.

i am storing data locally on computer and Number of vertices are 6636 and also if i delete the field and rerun the script qgis is crashing

Here are a couple upgrades for your script:

Layer scope context doesn't need to be recreated for every feature
Updating values through dataProvider() is faster (skips the undo/redo buffer stack).

With this your script shouldn't take more than a fraction of a second to run on ~3000 features
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

def pipe_f():
    Pipe_name = "PIPE"
    Pipe = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(Pipe_name)[0]

    #For Length
    
    Length = QgsField('LENGTH', QVariant.Double, len=10, prec=2)  
    Pipe.dataProvider().addAttributes([Length])
    Pipe.updateFields()

    # Create an expression context for evaluating the expression
    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(Pipe))

    # Define the expression
    expression_str = "$length"
    expression = QgsExpression(expression_str)
    
    dict_change = {}
    index_field = Pipe.fields().indexOf("LENGTH")

    # Loop through features and update the field
    for feature in Pipe.getFeatures():


        # Evaluate the expression for each feature
        context.setFeature(feature)
        value = expression.evaluate(context)
        
        dict_change[feature.id()] = {index_field: value}
        
    # Update the new field with the calculated value
    Pipe.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(dict_change)
    
pipe_f()


Thank you so much sir you are like a saviour i was trying to get this method for 4 days, thank you so much

Dear sir i have a favor to ask can you guide me to suggest any course or playlists on any platform to learn pygis in detail

The pyqgis documentation cookbook is a good starting point https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/fr/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html afterward going through the pyqgis API documentation and this StackExchange works. At least that is what I did.

Thank you so much sir
